# SQL Join two tables statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I was just wondering if anybody would be able to help me with a SQL join as I'm fairly new to MySQL. I'm looking to join two tables, here my tables and what I'm looking for the end result to look like, thanks in advance!

```
TABLE ARTICLES 
article_id    title    body            date       category     author
1             Lorem    Lorem ipsum..   1/1/2013   1            Mitchell

TABLE CATEGORIES
category_id   category
1             Web Design
```

SQL STATEMENT

```
select categories.category_id, categories.category as category
from categories left outer join articles on categories.category = articles.category
```

SQL RESULT I'M LOOKING FOR

```
article_id    title    body            date       category     author
1             Lorem    Lorem ipsum..   1/1/2013   Web Design   Mitchell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your joining `ON` condition should be between `categories.category_id` and `articles.category`. Otherwise,  you just need to add more columns to your `SELECT` list, as you're nearly there.

```
SELECT
  article_id,
  title,
  body,
  date,
  categories.category,
  author
FROM
  articles
  LEFT JOIN categories ON articles.category = categories.category_id
```

Here it is in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e0c1/1

I note that you have listed your date in the format `m/d/yyyy` here instead of `YYYY-MM-DD` which is MySQL's default output. If that is indeed how you have stored it in your table (as a `VARCHAR()` rather than [a proper `DATE` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)), I would recommend changing that strategy before you get too far into the project to change it easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  article_id,
  title,
  body,
  date,
  categories.category,
  author
FROM
articles 
  LEFT JOIN categories ON articles.category = categories.category_id
```

This article will help you in MYSQL a lot, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html